# XSLT . call another template with xsl:param

Tags: xslt

I am new to xslt and trying to create one XSLT ,
I am calling aother template with passing param value to it
But somehow blank value is coming in param variable for destination template.

Here is the simplified sample xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<TCXML xmlns="http://www.tcxml.org/Schemas/TCXMLSchema">
 <BOMWindow elemId="id62" revision_rule="id60" top_line="id2">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id1" label="a00pC7EtM1CZ7D"/>

</BOMWindow>

 <IMAN_Drawing elemId="id78" owning_site="id4" primary_object="#id21" secondary_object="#id25" user_data="">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id50" label="R8D9sTvgBT4jNA"/>

</IMAN_Drawing>
  <IMAN_Drawing elemId="id79" owning_site="#id4" primary_object="#id22" secondary_object="#id26" user_data="">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id56" label="R8D9sTfVBT4jNA"/>

</IMAN_Drawing>
  <IMAN_Drawing elemId="id80" owning_site="#id4" primary_object="#id20" secondary_object="#id24" user_data="">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id44" label="R8A9sTu6BT4jNA"/>

</IMAN_Drawing>



<UGPART creation_date="2012-06-05T09:25:30Z" date_released="2012-06-05T09:25:33Z" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id117" format_used="PART" gov_classification="" object_name="Test"  owning_organization=""  >

    <GSIdentity elemId="id21" label="RXM9sPifBT4jNA"/>

</UGPART>
 <UGPART creation_date="2012-06-05T09:25:30Z" date_released="2012-06-05T09:25:33Z" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id117" format_used="PART" gov_classification="" object_name="Test2"  owning_organization=""  >

    <GSIdentity elemId="id20" label="R3K9sPifBT4jNA"/>

</UGPART>
 <UGPART creation_date="2012-06-05T09:25:30Z" date_released="2012-06-05T09:25:33Z" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id117" format_used="PART" gov_classification="" object_name="Test3"  owning_organization=""  >

    <GSIdentity elemId="id22" label="xuO9sPifBT4jNA"/>

</UGPART>
```

In XML there are 3 IMAN_Drawing tags, and 3 UGPART tags

Here is my xslt for this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:plm="http://www.tcxml.org/Schemas/TCXMLSchema" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/plm:TCXML/plm:IMAN_Drawing">  
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
    <xsl:for-each select="/plm:TCXML/plm:IMAN_Drawing">
        <xsl:variable name="currentSecObjectId" select="@secondary_object"/>
        <xsl:variable name="RefSecObjectId" select="substring($currentSecObjectId,2)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="currentPrimaryObjectId" select="/plm:TCXML/plm:IMAN_Drawing/@primary_object"/>
        <xsl:variable name="RefPrimaryObjectId" select="substring($currentPrimaryObjectId,2)"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="UGPart">
            <xsl:with-param name="PriId" select="$RefPrimaryObjectId"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:apply-templates/>  

</xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="/plm:TCXML/plm:UGPART" name="UGPart">
    <xsl:param name="PriId"/>
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:if test="@object_name="'Test'">
        <xsl:attribute name="owning_organization">
            <xsl:value-of select="$PriId"/>
        </xsl:attribute>        
    </xsl:if>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(name()='owning_organization')]" /> 
    <xsl:apply-templates /> 
    </xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the output is :
owning_organization=""

Expected Result is :
It should update owning_organization attribute which i am passing from template 1 with value = $RefPrimaryObjectId for UGPART when its @object_name="'Test'"

what is going wrong here ? why $RefPrimaryObjectId" value is not coming to second template.

Comment: Are you sure that /plm:TCXML/plm:IMAN_Drawing/@secondary_object contains a value and exists?

Comment: If it's not huge, can you provide the XML input (by *editing* your original question)? If it is huge, then please try and trim it down to a level that's easy to see the problem but still creates the problem

Comment: You forgot to provide an XML document snd you havent provided a complete transformation -- the error is based on the missing information. Please, edit the question and provide a complete (but as small as possible) XML document and a complete transformation, so that we can run the transformation and repro the reported issue.

Comment: There's a certain amount of nonsense here: `<xsl:copy-of select="@*" />` does nothing because the document node has no attributes, and the call-template would probably be better done using apply-templates, and the parameter is unnecessary because you can get the attribute value relative to the context node. But none of those is the cause of your problem.

Comment: @Woody ,@ Dimitre Novatchev  - added sample xml file and my xslt you  can chek value is there for /plm:TCXML/plm:IMAN_Drawing/@secondary_object , but somehow value  isnot coming to second tempalte , i amy doing something wrong here.

Comment: Now you just need to add your expected output document!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really supply your expected output, otherwise it is really hard to understand what you want. I am making some-what of a guess as to your expected output based on your provided style-sheet.

I mean no disrespect and I am only trying to be helpful, but your style-sheet points  to so many misconceptions, that rather than just picking my solution (provided below), you might be better off in the long term, by putting pens down and working through some published tutorials, or reading a book.

Any way ...

This style-sheet ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:plm="http://www.tcxml.org/Schemas/TCXMLSchema" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="plm:IMAN_Drawing">
 <xsl:variable name="id" select="substring(@primary_object,2)" /> 
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
 </xsl:copy>
  <xsl:for-each select="../plm:UGPART[plm:GSIdentity/@elemId=$id]" >
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name()!='owning_organization' or ../@object_name!='Test']"/>
     <xsl:if test="@object_name='Test'">
      <xsl:attribute name="owning_organization"><xsl:value-of select="$id" /></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>  
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:for-each>  
</xsl:template >

<xsl:template match="plm:UGPART" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... when applied to your sample input, will produce output ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TCXML xmlns="http://www.tcxml.org/Schemas/TCXMLSchema">
 <BOMWindow elemId="id62" revision_rule="#id60" top_line="#id2">
    <GSIdentity elemId="id1" label="a00pC7EtM1CZ7D" />
</BOMWindow>
 <IMAN_Drawing elemId="id78" owning_site="#id4" primary_object="#id21" secondary_object="#id25" user_data="" /><UGPART creation_date="2012-06-05T09:25:30Z" date_released="2012-06-05T09:25:33Z" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id117" format_used="PART" gov_classification="" object_name="Test" owning_organization="id21">
    <GSIdentity elemId="id21" label="RXM9sPifBT4jNA" />
</UGPART>
  <IMAN_Drawing elemId="id79" owning_site="#id4" primary_object="#id22" secondary_object="#id26" user_data="" /><UGPART creation_date="2012-06-05T09:25:30Z" date_released="2012-06-05T09:25:33Z" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id117" format_used="PART" gov_classification="" object_name="Test3" owning_organization="">
    <GSIdentity elemId="id22" label="xuO9sPifBT4jNA" />
  </UGPART>
  <IMAN_Drawing elemId="id80" owning_site="#id4" primary_object="#id20" secondary_object="#id24" user_data="" /><UGPART creation_date="2012-06-05T09:25:30Z" date_released="2012-06-05T09:25:33Z" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id117" format_used="PART" gov_classification="" object_name="Test2" owning_organization="">
    <GSIdentity elemId="id20" label="R3K9sPifBT4jNA" />
</UGPART>
</TCXML>
```

Let us know if I have misunderstood your expected output.